# When I start using ngRoute my application get broken

Tags: angularjs

before i start using the routing and using just controller in my angular file it works perfect and these is my application without ng-route
[image: Text]
and these is with config function "using ngRoute"
[image: Text]
This is the main html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
        <!-- Here is Your Website Start-->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img\icon.png">
    <title>Shopment</title>
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <ng-include src="'include/navbar.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
        <!-- Here is Your Website End-->
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

if I just used controller it works , when I start using config function its getting broken

```
//module that define our application 
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

// config that controlles all the application's URLs

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/stores' , {
        templateUrl:'views/stores.html'
    }).when('home' , {
        templateUrl:'views/home.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/stores'
    })
});

// Controller that control signIn page
//
// we have to define our dependencies before the function in a single array item then define it again 
// in the function arguments
//
myApp.controller('main',["$scope",function($scope){

    $scope.removeItem = function(man){
        var removeMan = $scope.people.indexOf(man);
        $scope.people.splice(removeMan,1)
    };

    $scope.addMan = function(){
        $scope.people.push({
                'name': $scope.newMan.name,
                'color': $scope.newMan.color,
                'rate': parseInt($scope.newMan.rate),
            });
            $scope.newMan.name="";
            $scope.newMan.color="";
            $scope.newMan.rate="";
    };
    
    $scope.people = [
        {
            'name':'ali',
            'color':'blue',
            'rate':40
        },
        {
            'name':'ahmed',
            'color':'black',
            'rate':540
        },
        {
            'name':'adhm',
            'color':'red',
            'rate':120
        },
        {
            'name':'kareem',
            'color':'purple',
            'rate':3000
        }
    ]

}])
```

the file that contains the stores view :

```
<div class="store">
    <div ng-repeat="man in people" class="item">
            <div><img  class="under-photo" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plain-red-tee-shirt-isolated-on-white-background-picture-id471188329?k=6&m=471188329&s=612x612&w=0&h=2I2iiScsLky2XB6J-KGC2hDBei9AfBlJsAVO4zdYn_s=" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item-photo">{{man.name}}</div>
            <button ng-click="removeItem(man)">remove</button>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addMan()">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="newMan.name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="color" ng-model="newMan.color">
            <input type="text" placeholder="rate" ng-model="newMan.rate">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

solve :
i was using two different versions of angularjs and agular-route so they wasnt working